# When moving a directory into another directory, is there a simple way to generate a failure when the target directory doesn't exist?

Tags: linux, command-line, mv

I had a habit of using `mv directory1 directory2/` thinking that if I mistyped the name of `directory2` it would fail and warn me the directory didn't exist. As it turns out, that's not the case.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this? (A failure when the target directory doesn't exist).

Comment: Note: I removed references to Bash because it's almost entirely about `mv`. There may be solutions that use bashisms, but certainly there are approaches that work in `sh` and other shells, *including* Bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mv -t directory2/ directory1
```

From [`man 1 mv`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mv):

> ```
> mv [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...
> ```
>
> `-t`, `--target-directory=DIRECTORY`
> move all `SOURCE` arguments into `DIRECTORY`

This option is not required by POSIX though. Your `mv` may or may not support it.

---

Example:

```
$ ls
$ # Nothing here so far
$ mkdir foo bar
$ # Let's move foo to bar/
$ mv -t baz/ foo   # Oops, a typo, with -t
mv: failed to access 'baz/': No such file or directory
$ mv foo baz/      # Oops, a typo, without -t
$ ls                        
bar  baz
$
```

Comment: Thank you. It's a weird syntax, but it does accomplish what I wanted, and it seems fully compatible with Ubuntu's mv.

Comment: @Dan It seems weird because we got used to `mv source target`. When there can be many sources, it's perfectly reasonable to specify them at the end. Note `mv -t` works easily with `xargs` or `find … -exec … {} +`, it's a great advantage. The same with `cp -t`. It took me few years to appreciate such details. In my opinion `cp -t foo/ …` looks (and works!) similar to `tar -r -f foo.tar …` and the syntax of `tar` is quite standard. Now I find `mv source target` little weird because of its "inconsistency": the result depends on whether `target` is an existing directory or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `bash`, and your `mv` command doesn't support the non-POSIX `-t` option, you can still define a function `mvdir` in your `.bashrc` file like this:

```
mvdir() {
    if [ -d "$2" ]
    then
        mv "$1" "$2"
    else
        printf 'mvdir: "%s" does not exist, or is not a directory\n' "$2" >&2
        return 1
    fi
}
```

With that function definition in place, you can then say:

```
mvdir directory1 directory2
```

In a more compact form, the command at the heart of this function is:

```
( [ -d directory2 ] && mv directory1 directory2 )
```

That logic is slightly expanded in the function to make it cleaner to present an error message in the case where directory2 does not exist, or is not a directory.  If the destination directory does exist, `mv` will execute, and any error message or result code will be raised by `mv`.  If the directory does not exist, then `printf` will write a diagnostic to `stderr` and the function returns a non-zero result code to indicate an error.

To test, start in an empty directory:

```
$ find *
find: *: No such file or directory
$ mkdir A
$ find *
A
$ mvdir A B || echo fail
mvdir: "B" does not exist, or is not a directory
fail
$ mkdir B
$ find *
A
B
$ mvdir A B || echo fail
$ find *
B
B/A
```